# Play Framework 2.2 Java with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.2

what's the best way to use MongoDB with PlayFramework 2.2 Java? Is there one that allows me to use the javax.persistence.Entity annotation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about an ORM for Mongodb ?

Reading this http://www.infoq.com/articles/mongodb-java-orm-bcd

I never used it but it seems that MJORM could do what you want :

http://code.google.com/p/mongo-java-orm/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mjorm/?r=3180